# I use XCODE and C++ but the function system("jq"); returns with sh: command not found. I can run jq from the command line

Tags: c++, xcode, system

I develop my c++ software on my MAC with xcode.

I have a program and I want to call curl and format the data with jq.
When I run/debug the program, the function

```
system("jq");
```

returns sh: command not found.

```
system("curl");
```

works fine.

When I run jq on the command line on my mac, it works fine.

Comment: It might be a path problem. You can check the path to jq and maybe include the entire path to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The $PATH for XCODE is not the same as $PATH for the system. I had to add a extra PATH to my scheme in XCODE to sovlve that problem.